# Why does Rust not automatically move when necessary?

Tags: rust

The following program compiles without issue:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    async fn g(x: String) {}

    let f = || {
        let y: String = String::from("a").clone();

        return async {
        println!("{}", &y);
        return g(y).await;
    }};
}
```

However, if the line "return g(y).await;" is removed, it will fail with the following:

```
error[E0373]: async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows `y`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:35:22
   |
35 |           return async {
   |  ______________________^
36 | |         println!("{}", &y);
   | |                         - `y` is borrowed here
37 | |         // return g(y).await;
38 | |     }};
   | |_____^ may outlive borrowed value `y`
   |
note: async block is returned here
  --> src/main.rs:35:16
   |
35 |           return async {
   |  ________________^
36 | |         println!("{}", &y);
37 | |         // return g(y).await;
38 | |     }};
   | |_____^
help: to force the async block to take ownership of `y` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
35 |         return async move {
   |                      ++++
```

Why does the same error not appear in the original code?

Answer (score 6):

Rust does the minimum amount of work necessary to get your closure to work.

```
let f = || {
    let y: String = String::from("a").clone();
    return async {
        println!("{}", &y);
    }
};
```

Here, the inner closure requires `y` by reference. So Rust is going to turn it into, essentially, a `struct` with a `&String`. Removing the async stuff for simplicity, it would turn this

```
let f = || {
    let y: String = String::from("a").clone();
    || {
        println!("{}", &y);
    }
};
```

into, effectively, this

```
struct MyCustomClosure<'a> { y: &'a String };

impl<'a> FnOnce for MyCustomClosure<'a> {
  fn call_once(self) {
    println!("{}", self.y)
  }
}

// (Same impl for FnMut and Fn ...)

let f = || {
    let y: String = String::from("a").clone();
    return MyCustomClosure { y: &y }
};
```

Now, sometime way *later on* in the compilation process, Rust realizes that the lifetime `'a` for `MyCustomClosure` doesn't line up with the lifetime for the enclosing function, and it complains. But by this point it's already committed to using a reference here and it's not smart enough to go back and try a different closure type. It's two different stages of compilation that don't talk to each other directly.

This on the other hand

```
let f = || {
    let y: String = String::from("a").clone();
    || { y }
};
```

This, on the other hand, very clearly requires a move. We're passing ownership inside the closure, so we get a closure that only implements `FnOnce` and that takes the `y` by value. Essentially we get

```
struct MyCustomClosure2 { y: String };

impl FnOnce for MyCustomClosure2 {
  fn call_once(self) -> String {
    self.y
  }
}

// No FnMut or Fn this time, since we need to pass ownership of a value.
```

Now there's no lifetime argument `'a` to cause conflicts down the road. There's just a simple struct and it all works out.

As the error message indicates, if your intent is to get an `FnOnce` which returns the string by moving, you can prefix your closure with the `move` keyword.

```
let f = || {
    let y: String = String::from("a").clone();
    return async move {
        println!("{}", &y);
    }
};
```

Comment: 1. Can you explain the "essentially, a `struct`"? I'm worried that's sweeping details under the rug that will create problems in the future.
2. What if you don't want to make the closure move (or one time)?

Comment: 1. `struct` is the Rust equivalent of a `class`, more or less. It's a collection of data, on which functionality can be defined. Exactly *what* a closure is isn't specified, but it's always possible to "fake" them with a struct, which is why I say it's equivalent. 2. You have temporary data that's going out of scope. If you did the same thing in C++, it'd be a segfault at runtime. Rust is reporting a legitimate concern. You can fix that by either making the closure one-time-use or by moving the value inside the closure. Your choice, but you have to do something.

Comment: I mean what is it *essentially* a struct—or do you simply mean a closure? I don't feel I can 100% predict Rust's behavior in situations like these so I'm looking for a 100% detailed answer.

Comment: I mean a closure. A closure compiles to something that can be replicated with a `struct`.  And I can't 100% predict Rust's behavior with closures either. General rule of thumb is: See if you can get away with a non-mutable reference first, then try mutable ref, then try move semantics. Take the first one that works.

Comment: @Test [The rules are here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/types/closure.html#capture-modes).